# Solve first order ODE $c_n'(t)+\lambda_n c(t)=a_n e^t.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So this is actually a sub-problem that arouse while solving a PDE. I ended upp needing to slove the following first order ode:

$$c_n'(t)+\lambda_n c(t)=a_n e^t.\tag1$$

Where $\lambda_n=-\frac{n^2\pi^2}{16}$ and $a_n$ is an unknown function of $n$. Now I assume that both $\lambda_n$ and $a_n$ are constants in this case and we shall treat them as such. So our integrating factor is

$$I(x)=e^{\lambda_n t},\tag2$$

multiplying both sides with this gives, by the virtue of the differentiation rule of products,

$$c_n'(t)e^{\lambda_n t}+c_n(t)\lambda_n e^{\lambda_n t}=\left(c_n(t)e^{\lambda_n t}\right)'=a_n e^t e^{\lambda_n t}=a_ne^{(\lambda_n+1)t}.\tag3$$

Integrating both sides to obtain

$$c_n(t)e^{\lambda_n t}=\frac{a_ne^{\lambda_n t}e^{t}}{\lambda_n+1}+b_n \Leftrightarrow c_n(t)=\frac{a_ne^t}{\lambda_n+1}+\frac{b_n}{e^{\lambda_n t}},\tag4$$

and finally

$$\boxed{c_n(t)=\frac{a_ne^t+(\lambda_n+1)b_ne^{-\lambda_n t}}{\lambda_n+1}.}\tag5$$

According to my book they have

$$c_n(t)=\frac{a_ne^t+b_ne^{-\lambda_n t}}{\lambda_n+1}.\tag6$$

I assume they have baked in the constant $\lambda_n+1$ into $b_n,$ by

$$c_n(t)=\frac{a_ne^t+\lambda_nb_ne^{-\lambda_n t}+b_ne^{-\lambda_n t}}{\lambda_n+1}=\frac{a_ne^t+2b_ne^{-\lambda_n t}}{\lambda_n+1}=\frac{a_ne^t+b_ne^{-\lambda_n t}}{\lambda_n+1}.\tag7$$

But why can't we then continue smashing in the denominator aswell and just get $c_n(t)=a_ne^t+b_n e^{\lambda_n t}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b_n$ is a constant of integration and can be redefined by you at will (to absorb other constants), but $a_n$ is given from the outset and is therefore not yours to redefine.